# How to automatically export table as a CSV in Oracle Application Express?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I would like to automatically export (say every hour) a view in my Oracle Application Express as a CSV file to be stored on the Apex Server. How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see this as an APEX-specific question.  The real question is: how to automatically export data as a CSV file in **Oracle**.  This can be done using the [UTL_FILE package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_file.htm#BABGGEDF) to create the file, and either [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI) or [DBMS_JOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD) package* to run your UTL_FILE procedure every hour.

(* DBMS_SCHEDULER is the officially preferred method, but DBMS_JOB is a lot simpler to use.)

Comment: link fix: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/server.815/a68001/utl_file.htm